# Build fails for physical device, succeeds for virtual simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My build fails for my iOS app when attempting to run it on a physical `iPhone 6s iOS 9.3`. It succeeds when running it on any simulator built in to Xamarin. I get the following error message:

`/project/path/iOS/Resources/Images.xcassets is a directory`

I have not used `Images.xcassets` and I do not care about its contents which are `Images.cassets/AppIcons.appiconset/contents.json`

Comment: Add screenshot of the whole error or paste it here

Comment: Add an image.xcassets in project or open project.pbxproj search for Images.xcassets remove where you find this line where you find them clean and build again :)

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't want to use Asset Catalogs:**

Open your `info.plist` file in `Xamarin Studio` and scroll down to the `Universal Icons` and `Universal Launch Images` and set "`Don't use Asset Catalogs`" for the `Source` dropdown:

[image]